# Overpass API - Exclude ferry routes from bicycle query

Tags: r, openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I am querying the Overpass API using `osmdata` in R, searching for all ways where `bicycle = yes` and would like to exclude ferry routes.

Below is my code so far and a picture of the map result. As you can see there in the map there is a protruding line representing the ferry route.

I've tried a few variations of `add_osm_feature("route", != "ferry")` but can't seem to get it working.

Is it possible to exclude ferry routes at all?

```
query_1 <- getbb("Copenhagen Municipality, Denmark") %>%
  opq() %>%
  add_osm_feature("bicycle", "yes")

query_1_sf <- osmdata_sf(query_1)

###mapping
map <- get_map(getbb("Copenhagen"), maptype = "toner-background")

ggmap(map)+
  geom_sf(data = query_1_sf$osm_lines,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          colour = "#238443",
          size = .5)+
  labs(x = "", y = "")
```

![
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `=` in the function call to `add_feature` is not a comparison, but rather passing the value of an argument, as opposed to `==` or `>=` which are used in *queries*, and some functions that accept comparisons.

In the man page for the function, the last example is this:
`q <- opq ("portsmouth uk") %>% add_osm_feature(key = "highway", value = "!primary")`

Which is illustrative of the syntax osmdata uses; you may pass it like:
`add_osm_feature(key = "route", value = "!ferry")` for your use case, or set it manually to slot `query_1$features` with:

`query_1$features = " [\"bicycle\"=\"yes\"] [\"route\"!=\"ferry\"]"`

[image]